# Find the last cell with a value in specific column

Tags: c#, excel

This has been asked a lot of times but I have never seen it like this.

How do I find the last cell with a value in col2?

Im going to use this later so iterate over that from row1 to the last row with data.

I want to modify this to only search through col2

```
nInLastRow = oSheet.Cells.Find("*",System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,    
false,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
```

My example:

```
      col1   col2   col3
 Row1 data   data   data
 Row2 data   data   data
 row3 data   data   data
 row4 data          data
 row5 data          data
```

In order to do this do i need so specify a range? But then again I don't know the size of the range. Ive tried with usedrange. But as the other cols(col1 & col3) have more data it is not appropriate.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will any of the columns have blank cells between data values or will the first blank cell always be after the last cell with a value?  If the latter then you can use `.End(xlDown)` (It is the equivalent of pressing `End + Down Arrow` on the keyboard.

Here is an example using VBA.

```
For Each rng In oSheet.Range("A1:D1")
   Set rngLastValue = rng.End(xlDown)
   Debug.Print "The last cell with a value in column " & rng.Column & " is " & rngLastValue.Address
Next rng
```